# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'fluidsynth': 'fluidsynth'

Tags: python, subprocess

The python code in question:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["fluidsynth", "-V"])
```

Steps to try to resolve:

- make sure that fluidsynth is installed. In terminal, I type `fluidsynth -V` and the output actually calls fluidsynth.
- attempted `os.system("fluidsynth -V")` but get the same error.
- also tried `subprocess.run("fluidsynth -V")` but to no avail.
- `which fluidsynth` yields `/usr/bin/fluidsynth`, and I checked that `/usr/bin/` is included in `$PATH`

I'm not sure why the code that I'm typing into the terminal stops working when I use the subprocess call. Any ideas?

Comment: Does calling `/usr/bin/fluidsynth` work? What error are you getting?

Comment: Oh. Wow. Cool! It worked!

Comment: This typically means that the `PATH` environment variable -- specifically, the value it has active while your program is running, as distinct from the version it might have in your interactive shell -- somehow got set to a value that doesn't contain `/usr/bin`. That's not normal, and you should be able to find the thing responsible in your environment or software and fix it; with a typical, correctly-configured system, your original code will work fine.

Comment: If you want to prove the above assertion wrong, adding `print(os.environ.get('PATH'))` _directly_ before your `subprocess.call` would be a way to do it. `echo "$PATH"` in your interactive shell just tells us your interactive shell's PATH; it doesn't tell us your Python interpreter's PATH, if it's started via some other piece of software (f/e, via an IDE, or a service definition, or who-knows-what-else).

Answer (score 0):

@jure c solved the problem by adding /usr/bin to the call

Comment: This is a workaround, not a fix. It won't work for anyone on a distro that keeps `fluidsynth` in a location other than `/usr/bin`. (It's even worse on distros like NixOS, where every time you upgrade a package version you get a different location for the binaries).